# Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string or a class/function but got: undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, axios, dispatch

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDCSs.png)The error specifically points to:

```
dispatch({
   type: SET_POSTS,
   payload: res.data
})
```

Below is my func code:

```
export const getPosts = () => dispatch => {
    dispatch({ type: LOADING_DATA })
    axios.get('/posts')
        .then(res => {
            dispatch({
                type: SET_POSTS,
                payload: res.data
            })
        })
        .catch(err => {
            dispatch({
                type: SET_POSTS,
                payload: []
            })
        })
};
```

I checked for imports, console.log(res) and everything seems fine, but the error always points to dispatch()

**Edit:**  After tracing the code with redux dev tools I found out that the payload for `SET_POSTS` kept changing from `payload:[{...}]`  to undefined. Below I attached the code for my reducer. I still don't know what the problem is.

```
import { SET_POSTS, LIKE_POST, UNLIKE_POST, LOADING_DATA } from '../types';

const initialState = {
    posts: [],
    post: {},
    loading: false,
};

export default function (state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case LOADING_DATA:
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: true
            };
        case SET_POSTS:
            return {
                ...state,
                posts: action.payload,
                loading: false,
            };
        case LIKE_POST:
        case UNLIKE_POST:
            var index = state.posts.findIndex((post) => post.postId === action.payload.postId);
            state.posts[index] = action.payload;
            // conditional from github
            if (state.post.postId === action.payload.postId) {
                state.post = action.payload;
            }
            return {
                ...state
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Here is where the getPosts() function is been rendered:

```
import { getPosts } from '../redux/actions/dataActions';

class home extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.getPosts();
    }
    render() {
        const { posts, loading } = this.props.data;
        let recentPostsMarkup = !loading ? (
            posts.map(post => <Post key={post.postId} post={post} />)
        ) : (<p>loading...</p>);
return (
            <Grid container spacing={5}>
                <Grid item sm={8} xs={12}>
                    {recentPostsMarkup}
                </Grid>
                <Grid item sm={4} xs={12}>
                    <Profile />
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        );

home.propTypes = {
    getPosts: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    data: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    data: state.data
});
export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getPosts })(home);
```

This is the `Post.js` file where the `post` prop is being passed in the `home.js` file.

```
class Post extends Component {
    likedPost = () => {
        if (this.props.user.likes && this.props.user.likes.find(
            like => like.postId === this.props.post.postId)
        ) return true;
        else return false;
    };
    likePost = () => {
        this.props.likePost(this.props.post.postId);
    }
    unlikePost = () => {
        this.props.unlikePost(this.props.post.postId);
    }
    render() {
        dayjs.extend(relativeTime);
        const {
            classes,
            post: { body, createdAt, userImage, userHandle, postId, likeCount, commentCount },
            user: {
                authenticated
            }
        } = this.props;
        const likeButton = !authenticated ? (
            <MyButton tip="Like">
                <Link to="/login">
                    <FavoriteBorder color="primary"/>
                </Link>
            </MyButton>
        ) : (
            this.likedPost() ? (
                <MyButton tip="Undo like" onClick={this.unlikePost}>
                    <FavoriteIcon color="primary"/>
                </MyButton>
            ): (
                <MyButton tip="Like" onClick={this.likePost}>
                    <FavoriteBorder color="primary"/>
                </MyButton>
            )
        )
        return (
            <Card className={classes.card}>
                <CardMedia
                    image={userImage}
                    title="Profile Image" className={classes.image} />
                <CardContent className={classes.content}>
                    <Typography
                        variant="h5"
                        component={Link}
                        to={`/users/${userHandle}`}
                        color="primary">
                        {userHandle}
                    </Typography>
                    <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary">
                        {dayjs(createdAt).fromNow()}
                    </Typography>
                    <Typography variant="body1">
                        {body}
                    </Typography>
                    {likeButton}
                    <span>{likeCount} Likes</span>
                    <MyButton tip="comments">
                        <ChatIcon color="primary" />
                    </MyButton>
                    <span>{commentCount} comments</span>
                </CardContent>
            </Card>
        )
    }
};
```

Comment: what happens when you remove dispatch from .then() call?

Comment: if I remove it then the it won't fetch the posts or the data. There will not be any errors appearing.

Comment: I think dispatch itself might be OK, but there's problem with rendering of elements in component that renders (I assume) list based on data sent in SET_POSTS action. Stack trace can be confusing sometimes or point to some weird stuff. Can you provide a code of component that is rendering these elements?

Comment: I provided that as an edit above. I checked where getPosts() is rendered and everything fine. SET_POSTS is used in a reducer and that also looks fine, I would provide the code but stackoverflow says its too much code.

Comment: Seems like you're not returning anything from `render()` function of your component.
Add `return recentPostsMarkup` at the end of `render()` and it should be working.

Comment: @svantetic I did dispatch it, but I get the same error. The console points me to my `Post.js` file, tells me to check the `render(), where the `post` prop is being passed in the `home` class attached above. I will attach the render from the `Post.js` code above.

Comment: @BensonYeung You are right. I have been tracing the error more closely and when using the Redux dev tools the `payload` for `SET_POSTS` kept changing from `payload:[{...}]` to just undefined. My other reducers are working perfectly. I will edit my post above so you can see the code for my reducer for `SET_POST`

Comment: What is the value of `SET_POSTS`? (Just guessing about the problem...) Any collision with the other action types?

Comment: @BensonYeung the value of `SET_POSTS` are objects. No collisions with other action types. Just mentioned once in the reducer and in the actions file in the `dispatch()` where the console traced the error.

Comment: I thought it should be a string. I mean its value as defined in `../types` through `import { SET_POSTS, LIKE_POST, UNLIKE_POST, LOADING_DATA } from '../types';`

Comment: Or might be there are other components that dispatches another action (e.g. `componentWillReceiveProps`) that resets your `posts` as shown in the screenshot?

Comment: @BensonYeung I don't have `componentWillReceiveProps` but I do call `getPosts()` in `componentDidMount()`. Also when I `console.log(this.props.getPosts)` I again get an empty array. What should I do?

Comment: thanks everybody! solved it. it was a very silly mistake with the imports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ciao, this is a well known issue in React. Please, check this [guide](https://blog.logrocket.com/common-bugs-in-react-native/#:%7E:text=Invariant%20Violation%3A%20Element%20type%20is,up%20default%20and%20named%20imports.) (even if is made for React Native).
In brief, your problem is related on how you are importing your component, and is not related on how you are dispatching your data.